# CSS issue: link is wrongly displayed

Tags: html, css

```
a {
    color: #000;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
```

That is the code I use. But, none of the links I have in my pages listen to this. They abide by this instead:

```
#menu li, a {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:1.2em;
    color: #575757;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Therefore a lot of the links are skewed, as they all float left and things.
The code for the links itself isn't wrapped in any way. At least not in a way that explains my errors.

```
<div id="footer">
  <p><center>Copyright 2008 - <a href="index.php">G.S.B.V. Pugilice</a></center></p>
</div>
```

That bit of code gives me two lines instead of one, the link floats left on the second line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you may be mis-understanding how selectors work.

```
#menu li, a { ... }
```

Means apply styles to any li descendant of a element with the id #menu **and** to any a found any where.

Did you actually intend:-

```
#menu li, #menu a {...}
```

?

Comment: I get the feeling that's exactly what he meant, especially given that the id is "menu". I think if you do what AnthonyWJones suggested you should find it behaving as you are intending.

Comment: Could I use the following: #menu li a {...}, without the comma after li? So that only links in the menu, within an li tag are selected?

Comment: Yes, that will select only the links in the list item.